# JS Classes, strange behavior

Tags: javascript, class

While working on my little project, I got a really strange error, and more strange fix to it.

Below I reproduced the error I encountered. What it does? When you press button "5 squared?" it should show 25.

As you can see, where is something `onlyfive()["Why it works???"];` in my code. And this is my fix. ;)

If you remove `["Why it works???"]` part sometimes it will be show as undefined in input.

But with `["Why it works???"]` I got an error message in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Why it works???' of undefined"

Basically you can write anything there, and it will still work.

ps. yes, I'm new to JS :(

**EDIT:** Ok, guys. Thanks, for answers. Solved problem by adding

```
static fivesqure(e) {
  if (e.square !== undefined) {
    testInput.value = `${e.square}`;
  }
}
```

Silly mistake.

```js
"use strict";
const testInput = document.querySelector(".testInput");
const testFive = document.querySelector(".testFive");
const testRandom = document.querySelector(".testRandom");
const testClear = document.querySelector(".testClear");

const settings = () => {
  let randomNumber = Math.random() * 9 + 1 >> 0;

  if (randomNumber === 5) {
    return {randomNumber};
  } else {
    onlyfive()["Why it works???"];
  }
};

const testClass = class testClass {
  constructor(e) {
    if(e !== undefined && e.randomNumber === 5) {
      this.square = e.randomNumber * e.randomNumber;
    }
  }

  static fivesqure(e) {
    testInput.value = `${e.square}`;
  }
}
const onlyfive = () => testClass.fivesqure(new testClass(settings()));

testFive.addEventListener("click", onlyfive);
testRandom.addEventListener("click", () => testInput.value = Math.random() * 9 + 1 >> 0);
testClear.addEventListener("click", () => testInput.value = "");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<input class="testInput">
<button class="testFive">5 squared?</button>
<button class="testRandom">from 1 to 9</button>
<button class="testClear">clear input</button>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you call onlyfive()["Why it works???"], it will expect a return value that is an associative array with a value associatively named *"Why it works???"* (e.g. `myFunction = () => { var myArray = []; myArray['one'] = 1; myArray['another_id'] = 365;return myArray; }
console.log(myFunction());
console.log(myFunction()["another_id"]);`. You are not returning an anything at all, so there won't be anything there - hence the error. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is just a mess.

When you call `onlyFive` and it does not return the random number 5, you don't actually return anything in the else clause that triggers onlyFive again:

`if (randomNumber === 5) {
    return {randomNumber};
  } else {
    // missing return here.
    onlyfive()["Why it works???"];
  }`

So any of those objects will not have a `this.square` property at all.
But since you use the value of the static call to fivesqure instead of the this.square propErty of the instance you're trying to make, you'll set undefined in the visuals while throwing an error:

`static fivesqure(e) {
    testInput.value =`${e.square}`;
  }`

My advice would be to:

1) use a placehodler value for this.square property so there's always a value.

2) Don't use static methods to init instances of a class.

3) Only use the instance values to populate visuals.

Answer (score 0):

You have an endless recursive call there:

```
onlyfive → settings → onlyfive → settings ...
```

This loop only terminates if you randomly find the value `5`. That value is passed to `new testclass` which passes it to `fivesqure` which assigns the value to the input.

Now, if you go into the `else { onlyfive() }` branch, that too will return a value to `new testclass` which will be assigned to the input, but that value in that branch is `undefined`, because there's no `return` in the `else` branch.

But if you add any `[...]` there, it will cause an error and stop the chain going back. Without that all the recursive calls will unwind and the first call of that chain will overwrite the value on the input with `undefined`.